# Grab a position of the Span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to generate a sequence of  elements that I would like to print out to the user. Each span element has a click a function attached to it, and when clicked, will highlight a different part of the program. So what I want to do is (after the  elements are generated) lets say this is what we have

```
<div id = "sequence label">
    <span>K</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>G</span>
</div>
```

I was thinking of grabbing the index of the span somehow when clicked and corresponding that with another index in a list so lets say:

```
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

so grabbing the first  element [0] will give me the data [2].

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: `$('span').index();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function

```js
var data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$("span").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  console.log(data[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span>K</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>G</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out really well. A lot better than the way I was trying to implement it by giving each span a number while generating it.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery a solution would be:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) { 
    spans[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var el = this, index = 1; el = el.previousSibling; index += el.tagName === 'SPAN');
        console.log('You clicked span number ' + index);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id = "sequence label">
    <span>K</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>G</span>
</div>
```

Or you would bind the index as an argument to the click handler:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) { 
    spans[i].addEventListener('click', function(index) {
        console.log('You clicked span number ' + index);
    }.bind(spans[i], i+1));
}
```

```html
<div id = "sequence label">
    <span>K</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>G</span>
</div>
```